# jQuery how to set first tab active?

Tags: jquery, tabs, selected

```
 $( '#xxx' ).tabs({
select: function(event, ui) { 
var theSelectedTab2 = ui.index;

if (theSelectedTab2  == 0) {
$('ul li.ep_s1').removeClass('ep_s1').addClass('ep_s-click1');
if ($('ul li#h13').hasClass('ep_l-click1')) {
   $('ul li#h13').removeClass('ep_l-click1').addClass('ep_l1');
}}
else if (theSelectedTab2  == 1 ) {
$('ul li.ep_l1').removeClass('ep_l1').addClass('ep_l-click1');
if ($('ul li#h12').hasClass('ep_sidebar_friends-click1')) {
   $('ul li#h12').removeClass('ep_s-click1').addClass('ep_s1');
}}
 }
});
```

if i use `selected: 0` it will set up the first tab as active but it will now go through the `if (theSelectedTab2  == 0)` statement and go through adding those classes.

if after the page loads i click on those tabs the script works perfect.

basically i want when the page loads the `if (theSelectedTab2  == 0)` statement and everything that happens inside it to be active.

thanks

Comment: have you tried using `trigger('click');` on the first tab ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger a click event on the first tab after page load?

Like `$('first tab selector').click()`

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the following line, after the tabs initialize:

```
$( '#xxx' ).tabs('select', 0);
```

Hopefully, it will also trigger the event you want.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do like this to make it work:

```
jQuery( "#xxx" ).tabs({active: 1});
jQuery( "#xxx" ).tabs("option", "active", 0);
```

Doing this way trigger the events soon enough

Answer (score 0):

that's what I'd do

```
$(function () {
    $("ul.nav-tabs li:first").addClass("active");
    $(".tab-content .tab-pane:first").addClass("active");
});
```