# jQuery UI Tab, set tab passive and active

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've 3 tabs. I want to set tab1 active and set another tabs passive. Only on first page load, It must be like that.

```
 <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">first</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">second</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">third</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
        ...
```

Comment: see this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624486/jquery-how-to-set-first-tab-active

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable a tab. The selected tab cannot be disabled. To disable more than one tab at once use:

```
$('#example').tabs("option","disabled", [1, 2, 3]);
```

The second argument is the zero-based index of the tab to be disabled. Instead of an index, the href of the tab may be passed.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-disable

Answer (score 1):

You could probably trigger a click event on the first tab on DOMReady. Something like:

```
$("#tabs ul li:first-child a").click();
```