# How to make this Clickable Tab to be onLoad

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am trying to edit this script to remove its function that you need to click the tab before showing the content. I want to display the default tab to display.
Please assist! Here is the code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#tabs li").click(function() {
       $("#tabs li").removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass("active");
       $(".Tablist11").hide();
       var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
       $(selected_tab).fadeIn();
       return false;
   });
});

</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trigger('click') on jquery tab's currently active tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735423/how-to-triggerclick-on-jquery-tabs-currently-active-tab) or [jquery how to set first tab active](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624486/jquery-how-to-set-first-tab-active)

Answer (score 0):

Give your default tab a class `active` then add this line to you script to trigger clicking on that tab:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#tabs li").click(function() {
       $("#tabs li").removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass("active");
       $(".Tablist11").hide();
       var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
       $(selected_tab).fadeIn();
       return false;
   });

   //add this line
   $("#tabs li.active").trigger("click");
});

</script>
```